# Setting an individual color palette for the group variable in geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset containing three groups (in this case soil samples), which are each containing measurements from two depth categories. I want to use the same colors for each group, but different shapes for depths. I managed that by using Depths for colorization and shapes, and later combining the legends.

But now i want to set up an additional geom_smooth using the same colors i used for geom_point. For geom_smooth i need the group argument set to the sample groups (not the depths), but i can not set a new scale_col_manual for geom_smooth.

```
df <- data.frame(X=runif(24, 0,1), Y=runif(24,80,100), Depth=as.factor(LETTERS[1:6]), 
                 Group=as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]))

labels <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X,Y,shape=Depth, col=Depth)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = labels ,
                      values = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red", "green", "green")) +   
  scale_shape_manual(labels = labels,
                     values = c(0,15,1,16, 2, 17))

p1

p1 + geom_smooth(aes(group=Group), method="lm", show.legend = F)
```

According to the color used above, the regression lines shown by geom_smooth should use `c("blue", "red", "green")`. Is there a way i can achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question. Is this what your want: `ggplot(df, aes(X,Y)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=Depth, col=Depth)) +
    scale_colour_manual(labels = labels ,
                        values = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red", "green", "green")) +   
    scale_shape_manual(labels = labels,
                       values = c(0,15,1,16, 2, 17)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(fill=Group), method="lm", show.legend = F)`

Comment: this colorizes the confidence intervals. I would like to colorize the regression lines.

Comment: This one: `ggplot(df, aes(X,Y)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=Depth, col=Group)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")) +
    scale_shape_manual(labels = labels, values = c(0,15,1,16, 2, 17)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(group = Group, color=Group), method="lm", show.legend = FALSE) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = rep(c('blue', 'red', 'green'), each = 2))),
           color = FALSE)`?

Comment: @mt1022 I was interested in how to do this too, and that works.

Comment: Thank you. That works as intended. You may want to post this as an answer.

Comment: glad it works. @RobertMc, I'll explain it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our goal seems to be coloring points by group and giving different shapes based on Depth.

If we add:

```
+ geom_smooth(aes(color=Group), method="lm", show.legend = F)
```

There will be two blue lines, as OP has set color scale manually with two blues for first two values. To get around, we can try:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X,Y)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Depth, col=Group)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")) +
    scale_shape_manual(labels = labels, values = c(0,15,1,16, 2, 17)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(group = Group, color=Group), method="lm", show.legend = FALSE) +
    guides(
        shape = guide_legend(
            override.aes = list(color = rep(c('blue', 'red', 'green'), each = 2))
        ),
        color = FALSE)
```

In this way, points and colors are colored by the same variable `Group`, so there will be no conflicts. In order to have shapes having corresponding colors, we can used `guide` to override its default colors. And in order to suppress the color legend for points and lines, we have to add `color = FALSE` in `guides`.

The result looks like this:
[image]